# DELETE Row of a table with a condition with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL which is working,

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Batch] B 
INNER JOIN BatchProducts BP 
ON (B.ID = BP.BatchID) 
WHERE Bp.ID = @ID AND B.RetailerID = @RetailerID)
BEGIN
    RETURN; 
END
DELETE FROM BatchProducts WHERE  BatchProducts.ID = @ID;
```

But it is composed with 2 statements. I want to use a single DELETE with a condition that RetailerID must match in BatchProducts table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
DELETE FROM BatchProducts
WHERE BatchProducts.ID = @ID
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Batch] 
    WHERE [Batch].ID = BatchProducts.BatchID AND [Batch].RetailerID = @RetailerID)
```

Comment: Did you miss @RetailerID?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you need to check if it exists?

```
DELETE bp
FROM BatchProducts bp
    JOIN Batch b
        ON bp.BatchID = b.ID
WHERE bp.ID = @ID
AND b.RetailerID = @RetailerID
```

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: For example a user from different retailer can delete a batch of other retailer.

Comment: But isn't that why I have included the @RetailerID in the query? The two queries are exactly the same?